# It is necessary use db.init_app or SQLAlchemy(app) is the same in Flask?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

Checking Flask and Flask-SQLAlchemy doc i have a confusion, if i have:

**models.py**:

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
#:Use or not
db = SQLAlchemy()

class User(db.Model):
 __tablename__ = "USERS"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(25), nullable=False)
    password = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=False)
```

**config.py**:

```
import os

class Config(object):
    DEBUG = True
    SECRET_KEY = os.urandom(12)
    SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS = False
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = "mysql://root:@localhost/example"
```

**app.py**:

```
from config import Config
from models import db
from models import User

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(Config)

db = SQLAlchemy(app)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    db.init_app(app)
    with app.app_context():
        db.create_all()
    app.run()
```

**is necessary use:**

`db = SQLAlchemy(app)` after `app.config.from_object(Config)`
or `db.init_app(app)` is the same?

Because i founded some examples of flask with only `db = SQLAlchemy()` in `models.py` and have `db.init_app(app)` before `app.run()`

And so founded examples with `db = SQLAlchemy(app)` override in `app.py` with no db.init_app(app)

I printed both values and get:

```
with only db in models:

<SQLAlchemy engine=None>
the problem is:
The app create the tables in my database
But engine=None

with db = SQLAlchemy(app) override

<SQLAlchemy engine=mysql://root:***@localhost/hsl_db?charset=utf8>

the problem is:
The app dont create the tables in my database
```

*What is the correct way to assign the database of SQLAlchemy to Flask app?*

Answer (score 14):

**From: https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/api/**

There are two usage modes which work very similarly. One is binding the instance to a very specific Flask application:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
```

The second possibility is to create the object once and configure the application later to support it:

```
db = SQLAlchemy()

def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    db.init_app(app)
    return app
```

The difference between the two is that in the first case methods like `create_all()` and `drop_all()` will work all the time but in the second case a `flask.Flask.app_context()` has to exist.

Answer (score 7):

There is no correct way as it all depends on how you want to instantiate your db using SQLAlchemy and app using Flask.
But I'll go over how I use the app.

```
def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__, static_folder='static', instance_relative_config=True)
    app.config.from_pyfile('app_config.py')
    return app

app = create_app()
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
```

Answer (score 2):

The Flask documentation recommends:

```
db.init_app(app)
```

[Flask Factories & Extensions](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/appfactories/#factories-extensions)